# Does white space impact compiling time?

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a node app with my friend and he insists to remove white spaces wherever possible. He would write arrays like this `arr=[1,2,3]` for example, because he sustains it will reduce the compiling time.

That clashes with my linter and I generally think it makes it difficult to read the code.

I understand that my app will be small and white spaces will not make any actual difference, but does it really have any impact? Do huge scale companies write it like this? Is there any convention about white spaces? I looked online but I can't find concrete or a consistent answer.

Comment: Yes, it saves about 3 nanoseconds.

Comment: Technically your friend is correct. However the compile time saved is far from worth the consequences. For example, it's likely all the time "saved" over a lifetime of doing this was far less than the time it took took him to explain his reasoning.

Comment: Readablity matters. Leave the code minimization to the packers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having extra characters in your code will impact the compiler, but the impact will be very very small. Your friends viewpoint can be applied to comments in your code: removing comments will make the compiler microseconds faster. However, it would greatly decrease developer productivity.

From the [Google JavaScript Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#features-array-literals), you can see Googlers do **not** leave out whitespaces. Take this example from section 5.2.2:

```
const a1 = [x1, x2, x3];
const a2 = [x1, x2];
const a3 = [x1];
const a4 = [];
```